# Limit Azure Active Directory sync

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory

We are setting up Azure Active directory sync, to have our users loaded into Office 365-portal. However, there are quite a number of users in our AD that I do not want to sync. Is there any way to configure the sync-tool to sync only certain users/OUs/groups, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is!
You can filter based on:

- OU
- Domain
- User attribute

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710171.aspx